# How do I work with keyboard shortcuts in WPF?

Tags: wpf, keyboard, shortcut

I have 10 check box items sorted alphabetically, say for example:

*Apple, AirCraft, Ball, Bottom, Cat, etc.*

By pressing the <kbd>A</kbd> key the focus must be set to the **Apple** check box, <kbd>B</kbd> - to **Ball**. How can I do this? These check box items are dynamically variable due to the item source count.

Since checkbox items are not hardcoded in XAML I cannot tag, I guess; I load them during run time. And what if I have items like the following?

1. **Apple**
2. **Apple1**
3. **Apple2**

In this scenario I can't set the shortcut right, so instead, if I press <kbd>A</kbd> the first item that starts with letter **A** will get focus and again pressing <kbd>A</kbd>, focus set to the next item that starts with letter **A**. If it reaches the last item that starts with letter **A** then again if I press <kbd>A</kbd> it has to go to the first item that has starting letter **A**, so this is my requirement:). How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the keyboard navigation by first pressing the alt key, and setting the check boxes content as:

```
<CheckBox Content="_Apple" />
<CheckBox Content="_Ball" />
```

Keep in mind that the associated keyboard shortcut will be the one after the "_" symbol.

Comment: Really thanx a lot, Now i Stuck up another Issue, I did as per ur guidence, Issue is, I'll load My checkBox items through Configuration file which are not sorted, so in code behind ill sort using Icomparer,when i use **_** for Shortcut, the Items are not getting Sorted.

Comment: My config looks **<Response DT="_Apple" />
   <Response DT="_Ear/>
   <Response DT="A_irCraft"/>
   <Response DT="_CERTIFICATION" />
   <Response DT="_Ball" />
                                 <Response DT="_Cat" />
                                <Response DT="_Bottom"/>
                                 <Response DT="_Dam" />**

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple to traverse items:

By pressing the <kbd>A</kbd> key, the focus must be set to the **Apple** check box, <kbd>B</kbd> - to **Ball**. These check box items are dynamically variable due to the item source count.

Just do it as below. Place the underscore symbol, **"_"**, before **"A"**:

1. **_Apple**
2. **_Apple1**
3. **_Apple2**

If I press <kbd>A</kbd> the first item that starts with letter **A** will get focus and again pressing <kbd>A</kbd> focus is set to the next item that starts with letter **A**. If it reaches the last item starts with letter **A** then again if I press <kbd>A</kbd> it will go to the first item that has starting letter **A**. If you want to check the checkbox you can use the <kbd>SpaceBar</kbd>. Provided checkbox items must be within ItemsControl.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to come up with some set of rules as to what key press results in which item - ie, if there are two "A" items, what item is selected on "A"?

Then you'll have to manually find the item that matches the entered keypress on a keypress and highlight it.

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to the `OnPreviewKeyDown` event of the container which holds your CheckBox items. Then implement what happens when a specific button is pressed.