# WPF read Checkbox.Content

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, textblock

I have a couple of CheckBoxes with a TextBlock as content.
Now I want to read out the TextBlock.Text from each Checkbox.

If I read out the content like `checkBox.Content.ToString();` I only get `System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock` which kinda makes sense.

I also tried to create a new TextBlock and give it the content but it didn't work.

```
  TextBlock _tempTBL = new TextBlock();
  _tempTBL = checkBox.Content;
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var _tempTBL = (TextBlock) checkBox.Content; //Get handle to TextBlock
var text = _tempTBL.Text; //Read TextBlock's text
```

**Edit:**

On a side note, you can directly set desired text as `CheckBox's` content.

`checkBox.Content = "Hello World";`

And when you want to access the text, no type cast is needed

`string text = checkBox.Content;`

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @mykds You can also directly set `CheckBox's` content as a string value, see my edit.

Comment: there's still an implicit cast, isn't there? `Content` returns a type of object.

Comment: @ps2goat: Absolutely! There is an implicit cast, we would just not need to 'explicitly' cast it.

Comment: I choose to use a textblock as content because of the accelerator key. The first underscore of my Label was always missing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40848408/xml-string-missing-char

Comment: And I have to cast it as a TextBlock as it throws me an error on _tempTBL.Text if I don't cast it.

Comment: @mykds You can put [underscore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246589/how-to-work-with-keyboard-shortcuts-in-wpf) in front of the text  or [use AccessText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.accesstext.aspx) for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

You have to cast the type to a `TextBlock`:

```
// no need to 'new' it up if you're assigning an existing instance...
TextBlock _tempTBL = (TextBlock) checkBox.Content;
```

Comment: I know you're just working with the code provided, but it should be noted that the `= new TextBlock()` is unnecessary as it just creates a `TextBlock` that's thrown away on the next line.

Comment: That's it. Thank you :-)

Comment: @adv12 Is there a better (cleaner) solution? Edit: Ah I see what you mean. sure the easiest way would be: TextBlock _tempTBL = (TextBlock) checkBox.Content;

Comment: @mykds, yes.  See Marshal's answer, which avoids creating a `TextBlock` that is immediately discarded.

Comment: @adv12- good point.  i didn't even look at it that fully =/.  I updated the answer with your suggestion.