# Checked items of checkbox of datagridview c#

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datagridview

I have added checkbox in datagridview and I want check whether an item is checked or not, and then read the content value, but I am little bit confuse how to accomplish it.
This is Xmal code

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="#">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox x:Name="checkboxinstance" Checked="checked_it" Unchecked="unchecked_it" content ="{Binding apiName }" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

This is behind the code:

```
private void checked_it(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List<CheckBox> checkBoxlist = new List<CheckBox>();
    foreach (CheckBox c in checkBoxlist)
    {
        //what I add here
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to know if a CheckBox is currently checked or not, or do you just want to check or uncheck it?

Comment: I want to know if a CheckBox is currently checked or not

Comment: As your CheckBox is called "checkboxinstance" use the IsChecked property. In your C#-Code where you can access your Checkbox: if (this.checkboxinstance.Ischecked) { // do something here }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `IsChecked` property to check if the checkbox has been ticked.
To read the value of the `Content` you have to cast the type to a TextBlock

```
foreach (CheckBox c in checkBoxlist)
{
     If (c.IsChecked == true)
        {
        //Code when checkbox is checked
        var _tempTBL = (TextBlock) c.Content; //Get handle to TextBlock
        var foo = _tempTBL.Text; //Read TextBlock's text
        //foo is now a string of the checkbox's content
        }
}
```

[MSDN link to the IsChecked property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked(v=vs.110).aspx)

[MSDN link to the Content property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I know this but i want to get the value of checked item

Comment: I edit post and now checkbox has some content and I want to get thi content if checkbox is checked

Comment: In datagridview if I check a row then how I get the value of the cell of that row

Comment: Thanks, but there is little bit problem foo contains value of object type but I need value of string type

Comment: seems you need to cast to TextBlock as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41129614/wpf-read-checkbox-content